# How to fix Argument must be a dense tensor error while converting numpy image array to tensor array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, opencv

I'm trying to convert numpy image array to tensor image array as below

```
img = cv2.imread(r'source_img.jpg')
```

img shape (128, 128, 3) and numpy array as below

> [[[102 102  94]
> [ 99 100  92]
> [ 98  99  91]
> ...
> [ 32  30  26]
> [ 32  30  26]
> [ 32  30  26]]
> [[112 113 105]
> [109 110 102]
> [108 109 101]
> ...
> [ 32  30  26]
> [ 32  30  26]
> [ 32  30  26]]
> [[144 145 137]
> [141 142 134]
> [140 141 133]
> ...
> [ 32  30  26]
> [ 32  30  26]
> [ 32  30  26]]
> ...
> [[ 79  77  73]
> [ 80  78  74]
> [ 81  79  75]
> ...
> [104  98  93]
> [100  96  90]
> [ 98  94  88]]
> [[ 80  78  74]
> [ 80  78  74]
> [ 80  78  74]
> ...
> [100  94  89]
> [101  97  91]
> [101  97  91]]
> [[ 81  79  75]
> [ 81  79  75]
> [ 80  78  74]
> ...
> [ 96  89  85]
> [100  95  89]
> [104 100  94]]]

when I try to convert into tensor array as below

```
tf.constant([img], dtype=tf.uint8)
```

I get error as below

> Argument must be a dense tensor: [array([[[102, 102,  94],
> [ 99, 100,  92],
> [ 98,  99,  91],
> ...,
> [ 32,  30,  26],
> [ 32,  30,  26],
> [ 32,  30,  26]],
> [[112, 113, 105],
> [109, 110, 102],
> [108, 109, 101],
> ...,
> [ 32,  30,  26],
> [ 32,  30,  26],
> [ 32,  30,  26]],
> [[144, 145, 137],
> [141, 142, 134],
> [140, 141, 133],
> ...,
> [ 32,  30,  26],
> [ 32,  30,  26],
> [ 32,  30,  26]],
> ...,
> [[ 79,  77,  73],
> [ 80,  78,  74],
> [ 81,  79,  75],
> ...,
> [104,  98,  93],
> [100,  96,  90],
> [ 98,  94,  88]],
> [[ 80,  78,  74],
> [ 80,  78,  74],
> [ 80,  78,  74],
> ...,
> [100,  94,  89],
> [101,  97,  91],
> [101,  97,  91]],
> [[ 81,  79,  75],
> [ 81,  79,  75],
> [ 80,  78,  74],
> ...,
> [ 96,  89,  85],
> [100,  95,  89],
> [104, 100,  94]]], dtype=uint8)] - got shape [1, 128, 128, 3], but
> wanted [1].

what am I doing wrong? any help or suggestion to rectify my error will be helpful thanks

Comment: `tf.tensor([img], dtype=tf.uint8)`?

Comment: tried got this error  __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value_index'

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: @I'mahdi ive included in qsn

Comment: You write I got below error, but i don't see your error, include full code and your error

Comment: @I'mahdi 
[104, 100, 94]]], dtype=uint8)] - got shape [1, 128, 128, 3], but wanted [1].

Comment: you input `(128, 128, 3)` image. why do you want get `[1]`?

Comment: thats the error i got

Comment: You can use `tf.constant(img[None,:], dtype=tf.uint8)` or `tf.constant(np.expand_dims(img, axis=0), dtype=tf.uint8)` where `np` is numpy